# Where does Chrome OS, linux (beta) mount usb devices when forwarded

Tags: mount, usb, chrome-book

I am running chrome os `Version 90.0.4411.0 (Official Build) dev (64-bit)` I have gone into settings and enabled my usb device and when I go into the terminal and run `lsusb` this is what I get

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0781:55a5 SanDisk Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The second one is my usb which I forwarded, but I can't find it in any directories and I can't figure out how to mount it. How would I do so?

Answer (score 0):

On my Chrome OS, Version 91.0.4472.81 (Official Build) (64-bit), I did the following:
Inserted USB storage and then right-clicked **Files** app and chose **Share with Linux**.

Then the USB storage is mounted at: `/mnt/chromeos/removable/` (see [here](https://support.google.com/chromebook/thread/23147554/how-do-i-mount-my-usb-stick-to-linux?hl=en) for reference).

**Additionally:**

In the question, by "gone into settings and enabled my usb device", did it mean having done the following steps:

- Linux development environment(Beta) --> Manage USB devices (and then enabling the USB drive)

Doing this removes the USB drive from being visible to the Files App, so the drive cannot be seen, and hence there will be no way to use the Share with Linux option.